# arsort with Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

How would one sort an indexed array and maintain the index association in Actionscript 3.0. The Array.sort(); method seems to reindex the array no matter what. Basically I need to recreate the [arsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) php function in Actionscript. Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do so you would need an associative array (i.e. an `Object`) because when the indexes are integers flash would automatically reorder them from 0 to *n* as you may have noticed (This can be quite annoying in your case, but has its reasons).

If you want to keep track of the key values, a hack is to store the indexes in the value for each item in the array :

```
var array:Object = new Array();

array.push({index:0,name:"Tom"});
array.push({index:1,name:"Andrew"});
array.push({index:2,name:"Mark"});

array.sortOn("name");

for each(var item:Object in array)
    trace(item.index, item.name);
```

This will trace :

```
1 Andrew 
2 Mark 
0 Tom
```

n.b. This can be improved if your values are strong typed in a `Vector` instead of an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#sortOn()